# How to implement grid based movement in a 4 Direction 2D Game?

Tags: c#, grid, 2d

I'm working on a 4 Direction (up,down,left,right) 2D game and it'll be with grid based movement, yet i can't figure it out to work it out.

public class Player : Character
{

```
/// <summary>
/// Overridin the characters update function, so that we can execute our own functions
/// </summary>
protected override void Update()
{
    //Executes the GetInput function
    GetInput();



    base.Update();
}

/// <summary>
/// Listen's to the players input
/// </summary>
private void GetInput()
{
    direction = Vector2.zero;





    //Movement
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
        direction += Vector2.up;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        direction += Vector2.left;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
    {
        direction += Vector2.down;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        direction += Vector2.right;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can do it two ways:

1. You could just add a value on x and y property and make sure that they don't have floating numbers on them. ie: x + 1 on going right, x - 1 on going left, etc.
2. Making a grid that the player could reference its movement to.

You will benefit more on making a grid first, and snapping your character to those grids. This way, you could restrict the character to follow the uniformed grid that you made with ease, and also use the grid for AI or NPC where they can do pathfinding.